# How do I check Paired Bluetooth Device is still there( still alive) using android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-arrayadapter

`btArrayAdapter` now contains all paired bluetooth devices. Later I want to check if those devices are still alive. If not, it should show me that device name.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(); 
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) { 
   for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
      String deviceBTName = device.getName();
      String deviceBTMajorClass = device.getAddress();
      btArrayAdapter.add(deviceBTName + "\n" + deviceBTMajorClass);
   } 
}
setListAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
```

How to check it?. Thanks

Comment: I want a message, whether still be able to connect to the device or not?

Comment: I hope this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008388/android-bluetooth-determine-if-a-paired-device-is-on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Bluetooth - Determine if a paired device is 'on'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008388/android-bluetooth-determine-if-a-paired-device-is-on)